# Run project with java options via sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I am running my fat jar with command `java -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/krb5.conf -jar my.jar`.

How to run my app with this option via sbt?
`$ sbt -Djava.security.krb5.conf="module\\src\\main\\resources\\krb5.conf" run` doesn't work. Error:

> ctl-scala>sbt -Djava.security.krb5.conf="ctl-core\src\main\resources\krb5.conf" ctl-ui-backend/run
>   Warning: invalid system property 'java.security.krb5.conf'
>   [info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\User\.sbt\0.13\plugins
>   [info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\ctl-scala\project
>   [info] Set current project to ctl (in build file:/C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/ctl-scala/)
>   [error] No valid parser available.
>   [error] ctl-core\\src\\main\\resources\\krb5.conf
>   [error]             ^

Comment: Have you tried `sbt "-Djava.security.krb5.conf=ctl-core/src/main/resources/krb5.conf" ...`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can force sbt to fork a new JVM when running the application, and set the desired java options with the following settings in the `build.sbt` file:

```scala
fork := true,
javaOptions ++= Seq(
  "-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/krb5.conf"
)
```

Simply run the `run` task and it should start the application in its own JVM with the required java options.

Comment: In the sbt shell you can try `show <project> / fork` and `show <project> / javaOptions` to check that their values are correct.

Answer (score 11):

Can you try `sbt -J-Djava.security.krb5.conf="module/src/main/resources/krb5.conf" run`

The `-J` causes the sbt launcher to pass those as options to the JVM.

Comment: doesn't work if `fork` is set to `true`.

Comment: @Vistritium how did you solve it for fork=true?

Answer (score 7):

As sbt manual it will pass JAVA_OPTS environment variable to the java and if you can not set the variable .jvmopts will hold the java commandline arguments. so if you are in bash :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/krb5.conf"
```

before sbt command will pass the argument to java runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is to use `.sbtopts` file. It should be in the root folder, next to `sbt.build`. Its content should be the java options, prefixed with `-J`, as written in previously answers, to tell sbt to pass those options to the JVM.
For example its content can be:

```
-J-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/krb5.conf
```